# html5 mobile capture camera and generate a preview box

Tags: javascript, html, camera, video-capture, mobile-browser

How can I capture the camera and start a 'live preview' on a little div on the on the page on mobile?

In the past I encountered some javascript web audio api that can allow you to create sound, manipulate them, start recording audio, buffer etc..

So I hope there is some similar solution also for the video stuff, so I could be able to start capturing video camera and pass data to the preview box on the screen

Here I found a link: http://mobilehtml5.org/ts/?id=23 that shows how to use `<input type="file">` to access to mobile built-in microphone and camera, but I'm not sure if I am on the right way..

Any help and suggestion will be really much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at this [html5rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/), it walks through the Javascript and markup necessary and shows a series of demos including how to apply CSS filters.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

I believe it has all you need.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-basic-demo
getusermedia does not work on any of my devices... I tried it on windows chrome,firefox, and android native browser... Is it hard compatible or I have to install something?

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm on Win 7 and all capture in the tutorial work tested in Chrome (latest). It does ask for permissions first but then it works.

Comment: my OS is windows vista... so does this mean that I can't test it?

Comment: What do you get if you run this in the browser console: `!!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);`

Comment: entering this in the console returns: **true** (chrome windows vista), how can check it on android?

Comment: You can debug android by connecting it to your desktop via cable, see https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging for some devices you might need to do some driver installation but should work, it is all written in the Remote Debugging guide.

Comment: Ho trovato la soluzione! Grazie mille per il tuo aiuto! Ti auguro Buona giornata :)

Comment: Ottimo, buona giornata anche a te! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81079/discussion-between-user3602937-and-giuseppe-r).